# JUnit Test Case for Java 8 forEach with Lambda Expression

Tags: java-8, junit5

I have one requirement to set values in iterating list by getting value from map. For this peace of code I have to write test cases using Junit and mockito.

```
  public void setAccountIdToAccountOrders(List<OrderLine> orderLineList, Map<Integer, 
       AccountFlexView> acctMap) {
                orderLineList.forEach(orderLineList-> {
                    AccountFlexView accountFlexView = acctMap.get(orderLineList.getAcctKey());
                    orderLineList.setAccountId(accountFlexView.getAccountId());
                    orderLineList.setInternalLeadAccountId(accountFlexView.getAccountKey());
                });
            }
```

Below in my test case but by using iterator that not mocking code inside forEach loop, which is actually using lambda expression.

```
@Test
 public void testSetAccountIdToPrismAccountOrders(){
     when(approvedOrderLineList.iterator()).thenReturn(iteratOrderLine);
     when(iteratOrderLine.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
     when(iteratOrderLine.next()).thenReturn(orderLine);
     when(prismAccountsFlexViewMap.get(any())).thenReturn(accountFlexView);
     when(orderLine.getAcctKey()).thenReturn(accountKey);
     when(accountFlexView.getAccountId()).thenReturn(DTF_LEAD_INTRNL_AC_ID);
     when(accountFlexView.getAccountKey()).thenReturn(accountKey);
     dashBoardServiceImpl.setAccountIdToPrismAccountOrders(approvedOrderLineList,
     prismAccountsFlexViewMap);
     }
```

If any one have idea how to write test case for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use Mockito (or any other mocking framework) here. Create real instances of `List<OrderLine>` and `Map<Integer, AccountFlexView>`, populate each with dummy data, invoke the method, then assert each `OrderLine` has the correct state after the method returns.

Comment: @Slaw thanks slaw I have did that real instances part as well, just wanted to know if there is any scenario to mock for lambda.

Comment: In this case, there's no reason to mock the lambda. The fact that `forEach` is used is an implementation detail. Your method could just as easily use an enhanced `for` loop or even an index-based, traditional `for` loop. What you care about is the result of invoking your method, not how it accomplishes said result.